# pimpl STL and DLL

Tags: c++, dll, stl

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Foo
{
private:
    struct Impl;
    Impl *pimpl;
public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo();
    Impl &GetVector();
};

Foo::Impl
{
std::vector<Bar> m_vec;
}

Foo::Foo() : pimpl( new Impl )
{
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    delete pimpl;
}

Impl &Foo::GetVector()
{
    return *pimpl;
}
```

I am getting compilation error with MSVC 2010:

> missing ';' before '&'

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Write `Foo::Impl &` instead of `Impl &` in the fourth line from the bottom.. Voting to close as typo. Note that you would have avoided this by using C++ **trailing return type** syntax (i.e., `auto` and VS 2015, it's free).

Comment: which line has the error?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I will need to compile it in C99 mode and not C++11, so no auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the return type of your `Foo::GetVector` function. Your `Impl` struct is contained inside of the `Foo` class, so in order to access it you have to write `Foo::Impl`.